# Getting a varchar back from a SQL Server 2008 Stored Procedure in a VB.net program

Tags: vb.net, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures, output-parameter

I'm trying to get a string (nvarchar) from a stored procedure in my VB.net program.  When I run the SP in SQL Studio, it's fine, but when I try to run it in the program I get the error:

```
Error converting data type nvarchar to int.
```

Here's my SP:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE cusVerifyAssignment
@assignment_number int,
@compass_or_anodes char(1),
@return nvarchar(1000) OUTPUT
    AS
    BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON;

-- Insert statements for procedure here
IF @compass_or_anodes = 'C'
BEGIN
    SET @return = 
    (SELECT CONVERT(nvarchar(1000), p.display_name + '|' + ISNULL(xro.release_type, '') + '|' + a.comments + '|' + a.assignment_id) as blah
        FROM Workplace_base.dbo.people p
        INNER JOIN Workplace_base.dbo.assignments a ON p.people_id = a.people_id
        LEFT OUTER JOIN Workplace_base.dbo.xro_assignment_release_types xro ON a.release_type_id = xro.release_type_id
    WHERE assignment_num = @assignment_number)
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    SET @return = 
    (SELECT CONVERT(nvarchar(1000), p.display_name + '|' + ISNULL(xro.release_type, '') + '|' + a.comments + '|' + a.assignment_id) as blah
        FROM Anodes_Compass.dbo.people p
        INNER JOIN Anodes_Compass.dbo.assignments a ON p.people_id = a.people_id
        LEFT OUTER JOIN Anodes_Compass.dbo.xro_assignment_release_types xro ON a.release_type_id = xro.release_type_id
    WHERE assignment_num = @assignment_number)
END
END
GO
```

Here's my vb code:

```
    Dim paramNumber As New OleDbParameter("@assignment_number", SqlDbType.Int)
    Dim paramDB As New OleDbParameter("@compass_or_anodes", SqlDbType.Char)
    Dim paramReturn As New OleDbParameter("@return", SqlDbType.NVarChar)

    Dim reader As OleDbDataReader

    paramNumber.Value = assignmentNumber
    paramDB.Value = "C"
    paramReturn.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output


    cmd = New OleDbCommand("cusVerifyAssignment", con)
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure

    cmd.Parameters.Add(paramNumber)
    cmd.Parameters.Add(paramDB)
    cmd.Parameters.Add(paramReturn)

    con.Open()
    reader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
    con.Close()

    Return reader.GetString(0)
```

I've tried using executeNonQuery too, but that got me the same thing.  Can anyone offer any suggestins?

Thanks

Comment: I changed it up a bit and rather then using an OUTPUT parameter, in the query I just select it and use the reader, so I've got a bit of hack, but I'd really like to understand how to get this to work.

Answer (score 0):

ExecuteScalar? Should allow the return of single value.